# com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider

Tags: android, firebase

Receving this error on **KitKat** and lower version running perfectly on Lollipop and above

I have included all the required jars in th gradle and Firebase json file to receive GCM.

**my app gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile project(':httpmime-4.2.5')
    compile project(':universal-image-loader-1.9.3')
    compile project(':universal-image-loader-1.9.3')
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.3'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This dependency includes the code for **all** of the Google Play Services APIs:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

This is very likely causing your app to exceed the 65K method reference limit, requiring you to use Multidex to run on pre-Lollipop devices.

You have two choices.  You can include only the Play Services APIs you actually need.  The [list is here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) in the section titled *Selectively compiling APIs into your executable*.  Or you can enable Multidex following the [instructions here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle).  Although you have `multiDexEnabled true` in your build.gradle file, that is only one of the three steps required to configure Multidex.  You also need to include the library as a dependency and update your manifest.

If you are using Android Studio 2.2.2, you can see how many method references are in your app using the [APK Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html).  From the menubar, select *Build > Analyze APK*.  The APK is in folder `.../app/build/outputs/apk`.  Select the APK file, and in the resulting window, click on `classes.dex` to see the number of methods and method references.

Comment: included only google play service which i actually needed...which resolve the problem...thank u

Answer (score 0):

Please update the firebase dependencies

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
    ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: thanks for your reply but it didn't solve my problem