# failed to register new user with firebase on android

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to use authentification service of Firebase but it didn't work, i get these errors:

> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
>   W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 9877480

Comment: Duplicate - 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/40748434/4427731

Answer (score 0):

Looks like dependency conflict. If you are using the latest version of the firebase libraries, you must update your Google Play Services. The error is saying that, your Google Play Service is not compatible with the firebase libraries.
If you don't want to update your Google Play Services, use the previous versions of the firebase libraries.